# Build an array of objects where some of the fields need remote data

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to build an array of objects where some of the fields need remote data. I wrote the following proof-of-concept and it works but the parallel arrays feel messy. Suggestions for something that keeps the keys and promises together would be appreciated:

```
async function p1(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`p1-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function p2(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve(`p2-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function t(n) {
  return { a: await p1(n), b: await p2(n), c: n };
}

async function r() {
  const keys = [];
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const key = `k${i}`
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(t(key));
  }
  const x = await Promise.all(values);
  const results = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    results[keys[i]] = x[i];
  }
  return results;
}

(async () => {
  const answers = await r();
  console.log('answers', answers);
})().catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'll try them in the actual code and see which is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my approach to `r` would be:

```
async function r() {
  const results = {};
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const key = `k${i}`
    promises.push(t(key).then(value => results[key] = value));
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);
  return results;
}
```

Note how `results` is populated in the loop (asynchronously), we only use `promises` so we know when everything's done (or, of course, that something failed). This keeps the key and value together in the loop body.

Live copy:

```js
// No need for p1 and p2 to be `asycn` since they don't
// use `await`; I'm guessing your real functions do
// (and don't use `new Promise`)

/*async*/ function p1(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`p1-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

/*async*/ function p2(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve(`p2-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function t(n) {
  return { a: await p1(n), b: await p2(n), c: n };
}

async function r() {
  const results = {};
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const key = `k${i}`
    promises.push(t(key).then(value => results[key] = value));
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);
  return results;
}

(async () => {
  const answers = await r();
  console.log('answers', answers);
})().catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This State Machine also works:

```js
async function p1(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`p1-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function p2(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve(`p2-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function t(n) {
  return { a: await p1(n), b: await p2(n), c: n };
}

async function r() {
  const results = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   const key = `k${i}`
   results[key] = await t(key)
  }
  return results;
}

(async () => {
  const answers = await r();
  console.log('answers', answers);
})().catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

This one too:

```js
  async function p1(x) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(`p1-${x}`);
        }, 250);
      });
    }

    async function p2(x) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
          resolve(`p2-${x}`);
        }, 250);
      });
    }

    async function t(n) {
      return { a: await p1(n), b: await p2(n), c: n };
    }

    async function r(questions) {
      return (await Promise.all(
        questions.map(async i => ({[`k${i}`]: await t(`k${i}`)})
        ))).reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, ...curr}), {})    
    }

    (async () => {
      const answers = await r(['1', '2']);
      console.log('answers', answers);
    })().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

The second one could be refactored better, but I don't know your eventual use-case. It uses [no variables and no loops](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/) though. That's the approach I'd go with.

Answer (score 1):

No need to cache the keys and values in a separate loop. U can build the results object on the go:

```js
async function p1(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`p1-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function p2(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve(`p2-${x}`);
    }, 250);
  });
}

async function t(n) {
  return { a: await p1(n), b: await p2(n), c: n };
}

async function r() {
  let results = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const key = `k${i}`
    results[key] = await t(key);
  }
  return results;
}

(async () => {
  const answers = await r();
  console.log('answers', answers);
})().catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```